# UIImageView height same size as UILabel font height. Centered inside UIStackView

Tags: swift, autolayout, uiimageview, uilabel, uistackview

I'm trying to take a label, followed by an imageView with the same height as the label's font, centered inside of a stackView.

[image]

For whatever reason, I can't figure out how to get this inside of a stackView. Here's what I got.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"same height as the label's font"*? Do you mean the actual character glyphs? That is, "an" / "and" / "AND" / "aj" / "ajd" all have different **character** heights, but the **label frame** will be the same height for all of those strings.

Comment: Hi @DonMag I'm looking for font size / point height? Something where the size of the image is approximately the size of the characters. - Similar to the first image. - Ideally all in a stackView

Comment: That doesn't answer the question... is this how you want it to look, with various different characters in the labels (label frame is shown with cyan background): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IXuS.png

Comment: Hi @DonMag That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: OK - you won't be able to do that with a `UIStackView`. You'll need to calculate the character glyph bounding box and then set the top and height of your image view.

Comment: Hi @DonMag I see. I'll convert these images to symbols then. I know it works with symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If the font size of the label is fixed, the height can be obtained.

```swift
(statusLabel.text as! NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : statusLabel.font]).height
```